# cron symfony command for sending email

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I am using symfony email sender command

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev
```

from dir `Desktop/workspace/symfony` 
now I want to use cron,I am trying to write

`* * * * * /home/user/Desktop/workspace/symfony php  bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev`

but this is not working
please help me, how to write in the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the PHP binary full path. Find it with 'which php'. Usually /usr/bin/php.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/Desktop/workspace/symfony bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev
```

Comment: Did you forget `/` between `symfony` and `bin`?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the command every 5 min (example)

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/yourproject/app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev
```